# Парсинг интерактивных Яндекс Карт python

Tags: python, парсер, яндекс-карты

Необходимо спарсить индекс качества воздуха с интерактивной Яндекс-Карты встроенной в сайт
https://rad.org.by/monitoring/air.html
Я новичек в парсинге и я не смог найти эти данные в коде страницы
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где находятся данные о качестве воздуха в html коде

P.S. Я понимаю, что выше карты есть оранжевая сслыка ведущая на простую html страницу с качетвом воздуха (письменная версия карт),
но я бы хотел научиться парсить с самих карт

[image: Индекс качества воздуха]

Comment: разве что с помощью selenium пробовать. загружать страницу кликать на элементы и потом уже парсить

Comment: спасибо, буду изучать его